# Доступ из одного класса к полям другого

Tags: c++, ооп

Здравствуйте.
Пытаюсь реализовать примитивный tower defence. Необходимо в методах класса *Tower* иметь доступ к полям класса *Enemy*. К примеру, в методе *shoot* класса *Tower* иметь доступ к полю *health* класса *Enemy*. Каким образом это реализовать наиболее оптимально и правильно?

```
class Enemy
{
public:
    Enemy();
    void move();
    void setHealth();
    float getHealth();
private:
    float health;
    float speed;
};

class Tower
{
public:
    Tower();
    void shoot();
private:
    float damage;
    float cooldown;
};
```

UPD:   На данном этапе дошел до такого. Кто что скажет?

```
void Tower::shoot(Enemy &enemy)
{
   while (enemy.getHealth() >= 0) {
      enemy.setHealth(enemy.getHealth() - damage);
   }
}
```

Comment: Уже есть геттер / сеттер `getHealth` / `setHealth`.

Comment: А каким образом мы сможем использовать геттер\сеттер внутри класса Tower?

Comment: Просто вызвав их, ведь это публичные методы.

Comment: Передавая enemy по значению здоровье убавится только у локальной копии.

Comment: Таак, забыл передать по ссылке, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Оптимальность и правильность зависит от целей и дальнейших ожиданий от классов.

Вы можете сделать так: сначала `Tower` а потом `Enemy`

```
class Tower{
//----------
//---------
};

class Enemy {
friend  void Tower::shoot(); 
//---------  
};
```

или написать так как вы, но сначала просто обьявить `Tower` и сделать его другом `Enemy`, а можно просто в `Tower` поменять спецификацию `private` на `protected` и сделать `Enemy` его наследником (скорее наследование стоит сделать закрытым).

Comment: В начале я думал о наследовании, но мне показалось, что это не совсем логично. Пришел к тому, что передал в метод shoot объект класса Enemy, и использую get\set для получения поля health.

Comment: так ведь если вам нужен доступ только к  health  то по логике gethealth его же возвращает, и ваша проблема отпадает, только остается думать о целесообразности сделать health общедоступным...

Comment: Хмм...Спасибо за идею, пойду пробовать!

Answer (score 0):

Не нужно давать Tower доступ к полям класса Enemy. Это нарушение инкапсуляции. Здесь вам нужен обмен сообщениями. Логика такая - башня стреляет в противника, он получает урон. Подумаем о деталях этого процесса. Есть 2 отдельных подпроцесса:

1) башня стреляет - только она сама знает, как она может выстрелить.

2) противник получает урон - только он сам знает, как он от этого урона поведет себя.

Вот каждый из этих подпроцессов и надо отдельно смоделировать, например так:

```
void Tower::Shoot(ITarget *target)
{
  int power = CalculatePower(); //тут может быть любой расчет того, как сильно вы бьете, может зависеть от множества факторов
// ...  
//далее может быть еще куча кода дополнительного, отрисовка, например или еще что
// ...
  target->GetShot(power); //передаем врагу сообщение, что мы его ударили, и говорим, с какой силой
}

void ITarget::GetShot(int power)
{
  int damage = CalculateDamage(power, hp, armor);
  if (damage >= hp)
    Die();
  else
    hp -= damage;
// ...  
//тут может быть еще куча кода дополнительного, отрисовка, например или еще что
// ...
}
```